# Vectorwise integration Pentaho

Tags: reporting, integration, pentaho

I have a problem regarding the integration of Vectorwise with Pentaho.
The Pentaho was working fine with other databases but integration with Vectorwise gives always the same error.

**AdhocWebService.ERROR_0012 - Failed to generate the report preview. Please check the server log for details of the error.**

When i checked the error log it said this :

**

> ERROR
>   [org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.connections.metadata.sql.SqlMetadataQueryExec]
>   SqlMetadataQueryExec.ERROR_0002 - Query execution failed:
>   QueryModelMetaData.ERROR_0001 -
>   !QueryModelMetaData.ERROR_0001_MetadataColumnNotFound! Generated SQL:
>   SELECT 
>             "BT_TIME_DIMENSION_TIME_DIMENSION"."cl_year" AS "COL0"
>            ,AVG("BT_TIME_DIMENSION_TIME_DIMENSION"."cl_week") AS "COL1" FROM 
>             "time_dimension" "BT_TIME_DIMENSION_TIME_DIMENSION" GROUP BY 
>             "BT_TIME_DIMENSION_TIME_DIMENSION"."cl_year" ORDER BY 
>             "COL0" ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine]
>   db143504-d7c1-11e1-b334-355c9beece81:SOLUTION-ENGINE:preview.xaction:
>   Action Sequence execution failed, see details below | Error Time:
>   Friday, July 27, 2012 1:35:40 PM IST | Session ID: joe | Instance Id:
>   db143504-d7c1-11e1-b334-355c9beece81 | Action Sequence:
>   preview.xaction | Execution Stack: EXECUTING ACTION: rule
>   (MQLRelationalDataComponent) | Action Class:
>   MQLRelationalDataComponent | Action Desc: rule | Loop Index (1-based):
>   0

**

when i run the same query directly on the Vectorwise server the output is obtained.

**Please Help me. Thanx in advance :)**

Comment: always strange if the exact same query executes fine via a sql client. Are you sure the BI server is using the same driver you are using when you test running the query?